# Sudo specific actions for specific directory

Tags: sudo

Ok what I want to do is use sudo,

I want to give access to a user to run the command:
    ln -s /source/location /destination/location

and only the above command with that location I don't want to give them all acccess to the "ln" command only "ln -s /source/location /destination/location"

Comment: If that is all the normal way to go is to create the symlink from your admin accout and NOT have the use bother with the command.

Answer (score 2):

Create file `/etc/sudoers.d/any-descriptive-name-here` with such content:

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/ln -s /source/location /destination/location
```

This allows `user` execute command `/bin/ln -s /source/location /destination/location` without password. Require password or not, create user list, allow by group, etc. - see [man sudoers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man5/sudoers.5.html)

Also note that delegating sudo permissions could more than easily open security hole.